# Java - use class defned in Main in another class

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors

I'm new to Java and we have to make this little project. So i have 3+ classes.

MY code is in pastebin
http://pastebin.com/GEq9DLiP

etc. etc.
Problem is, that in 3rd class it sais

```
"kangelane cannot be resolved"
```

but kangelane is already "defined" in Main.java and they are in same package.
Oh and Eclipse also wants to add "open bracet" after

`int sook = 4;` or

```
int dam;
```

and also "clode bracket" to the end
even though all open brackets are closed and vice versa

I have Getters and Setters in "Voitleja.java", so that works.
It also worked, when i only had 2 classes not 3 (Voitlus was in Main)

Comment: Could you post the code here? I do not see the class definition for Kangelane?

Comment: In main.java
"Voitleja kangelane = new Voitleja(nimi, 55, 12);"

Comment: You should also consider using English variable names. You have to admit `setLives()` and `setStrength()` sound a bit more sane than `setElud()` and `setTugevus()`.

Comment: Thanks for that, fellow Estonian, but this is a mini-project for my university. But i keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that main is a static class, if you want to use a variable in both main and in an oter class, you have to defined it as a static variable, for your example you should do :

```
public class Main {
static Voitleja kangelane;
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                    String nimi = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sisestage võitleja nimi");
                    kangelane = new Voitleja(nimi, 55, 12);
            }
    }
```

Then in your other class (assuming the import are correct)

```
        public class Voitlus{
            Random generator = new Random();
            int dam;
            int sook = 4;
            while (true) {
                    Main.kangelane.setElud(kangelane.getElud() + 7);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that resolved the bigger problem, now why is it asking for "{" after "int dam;" ?
http://pastebin.com/kRu8izLL

Comment: Sometimes Eclipse keep in mind what you've done before and don't refresh properly, try to close it and rerun again (maybe clean up your project too), at first look there is no other explication. Try to compile just with command line to be sure there is an Eclipse problem

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nimi = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sisestage võitleja nimi");
    Voitleja kangelane = new Voitleja(nimi, 55, 12);
}
```

(later)

```
while (true) {
    kangelane.setElud(kangelane.getElud() + 7);
}
```

The variables are in a different scope. You have to declare `kangelane` right after your `public class` declaration so both methods can "see" it.

Comment: @user2128837 Ummm... `public Voitleja kangelane;`

Comment: `public class ClassContainingMain { Voitleja kangelane = new Voitleja(nimi, 55, 12);// rest of class`